# Broken icon in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, icon

I have installed the Outlook app in my iPad mini and after some update the icon doesn't display correctly. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way of solving this without waiting for another update or reinstalling the app?

Comment: Probably not, but let's hear what the rest of the community has to say. BTW, IMO Outlook is not very good.

Comment: Depends what you want it for... IMO, it's a better Gmail client than the Gmail app.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to delete it. I would then shut down and then power the phone back up. Then re-download it from the App Store.

As iPhones run what is essentially a "simplified" version of OS X there are lot less options when it comes to troubleshooting as you don't really have ready access to the underpinnings of IOS the way you do OS X.

Comment: Long time ago I know, but this didn’t work for me, icons still generic. But thanks for the suggestions